# Detecting patterns in OHLC data from an existing pattern

Tags: programming

I have the following set of OHLC data:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 6, 30), '0.00013449', '0.00013866', '0.00013440', '0.00013857', '430864.00000000', 1593579599999, '59.09906346', 1885, '208801.00000000', '28.63104974', '0', 3.0336828016952944], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 7, 0), '0.00013854', '0.00013887', '0.00013767', '0.00013851', '162518.00000000', 1593581399999, '22.48036621', 809, '78014.00000000', '10.79595625', '0', -0.02165439584236435], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 7, 30), '0.00013851', '0.00013890', '0.00013664', '0.00013780', '313823.00000000', 1593583199999, '43.21919087', 1077, '157083.00000000', '21.62390537', '0', -0.5125983683488642], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 8, 0), '0.00013771', '0.00013818', '0.00013654', '0.00013707', '126925.00000000', 1593584999999, '17.44448931', 428, '56767.00000000', '7.79977280', '0', -0.46474475346744676], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 8, 30), '0.00013712', '0.00013776', '0.00013656', '0.00013757', '62261.00000000', 1593586799999, '8.54915420', 330, '26921.00000000', '3.69342184', '0', 0.3281796966161107], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 9, 0), '0.00013757', '0.00013804', '0.00013628', '0.00013640', '115154.00000000', 1593588599999, '15.80169390', 510, '52830.00000000', '7.24924784', '0', -0.8504761212473579], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 9, 30), '0.00013640', '0.00013675', '0.00013598', '0.00013675', '66186.00000000', 1593590399999, '9.02070446', 311, '24798.00000000', '3.38107106', '0', 0.25659824046919455], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 10, 0), '0.00013655', '0.00013662', '0.00013577', '0.00013625', '56656.00000000', 1593592199999, '7.71123423', 367, '27936.00000000', '3.80394497', '0', -0.2196997436836377], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 10, 30), '0.00013625', '0.00013834', '0.00013625', '0.00013799', '114257.00000000', 1593593999999, '15.70194874', 679, '56070.00000000', '7.70405037', '0', 1.2770642201834814], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 11, 0), '0.00013812', '0.00013822', '0.00013630', '0.00013805', '104746.00000000', 1593595799999, '14.39147417', 564, '46626.00000000', '6.39959586', '0', -0.05068056762237037], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 11, 30), '0.00013805', '0.00013810', '0.00013720', '0.00013732', '37071.00000000', 1593597599999, '5.10447229', 231, '16349.00000000', '2.25258584', '0', -0.5287939152480996], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 12, 0), '0.00013733', '0.00013741', '0.00013698', '0.00013724', '27004.00000000', 1593599399999, '3.70524540', 161, '15398.00000000', '2.11351192', '0', -0.06553557125171522], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 12, 30), '0.00013724', '0.00013727', '0.00013687', '0.00013717', '27856.00000000', 1593601199999, '3.81864840', 140, '11883.00000000', '1.62931445', '0', -0.05100553774411102], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 13, 0), '0.00013716', '0.00013801', '0.00013702', '0.00013741', '83867.00000000', 1593602999999, '11.54964001', 329, '42113.00000000', '5.80085155', '0', 0.18226888305628908], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 13, 30), '0.00013741', '0.00013766', '0.00013690', '0.00013707', '50299.00000000', 1593604799999, '6.90474065', 249, '20871.00000000', '2.86749244', '0', -0.2474346845207872], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 14, 0), '0.00013707', '0.00013736', '0.00013680', '0.00013704', '44745.00000000', 1593606599999, '6.13189248', 205, '14012.00000000', '1.92132206', '0', -0.02188662727072625], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 14, 30), '0.00013704', '0.00014005', '0.00013703', '0.00013960', '203169.00000000', 1593608399999, '28.26967457', 904, '150857.00000000', '21.00600041', '0', 1.8680677174547595]]
```

That looks like that, when plotted:
[image]

I'm trying to do the following: detect in other sets of OHLC data a pattern that looks like the one above. It doesn't have to be the same, it only needs to be **similar** to that one, the number of candles doesn't have to be the same. What needs to be similar is only the shape of it.

**What i tried:**
Until now, i only managed to cut away manually the OHLC data that i don't need, so that i can only have the patterns i want. Then, i plotted it using a pandas dataframe:

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([x[:6] for x in OHLC], 
                          columns=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])

format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format=format)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']))
df["Open"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Open"],errors='coerce')
df["High"] = pd.to_numeric(df["High"],errors='coerce')
df["Low"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Low"],errors='coerce')
df["Close"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Close"],errors='coerce')
df["Volume"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Volume"],errors='coerce')


mpf.plot(df, type='candle', figscale=2, figratio=(50, 50))
```

**What i thought:** A possible solution to this problem is using Neural Networks, so i would have to feed images of the patterns i want to a NN and let the NN loop though other charts and see if it can find the patterns i specified. Before going this way, i was looking for simpler solutions, since i don't know much about Neural Networks and i don't know what kind of NN i would need to do and what tools would i be supposed to use.

Another solution i was thinking about was the following: i would need, somehow, to convert the pattern i want to find on other datasets in a series of values. So for example the OHLC data i posted above would be quantified, somehow, and on another set of OHLC data i would just need to find values that get close to the pattern i want. This approach is very empirical for now and i don't know how to put that in code. I think this process is called normalization.

A tool i was suggested to use: [Stumpy](https://pypi.org/project/stumpy/)

**What i need:**
I don't need the exact code, i only need an example, an article, a library or any kind of source that can point me out on how to work when i want to detect a certain pattern specified by me on a OHLC data set. I hope i was specific enough; any kind of advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> A possible solution to this problem is using Neural Networks ...

Recently there have been some academic papers about "Financial Vision" which would seem to meet your need, but they do involve deep neural networks, which might be a steep learning curve for you.

The link to the github is https://github.com/pecu/FinancialVision from which you can get access to the papers themselves plus Python code/toolboxes etc.

If this is too much

> another solution I was thinking ...

of is to use a framework based on the [MNIST_database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database). The MNIST database is a digit recognition database that has been crawled over for many years by researchers and there are literally many dozens of algorithms/machine learning techniques that have been trained on this data set and which are easily available online at e.g. github. All you need to do take one of these and substitute your candlestick patterns in place of the database digits training set.

To convert candlesticks to the required "pixel" format similar to the digits, just create a zero filled grid of say 10 rows and 10 columns, the 1st row is the max high of the candlestick pattern and the 10th row the min low, and each column represents 1 complete candlestick. Put each candlestick's separate ohlc value into the nearest rounded row level for each candlestick column, represented by the value 1, and then "unroll" this grid in to a 1 by 100 vector of 40 value 1s and 60 zeros, which exactly mirrors the format of the MNIST database, but with 100 notional pixels. Give a label to each pattern, e.g. 1 to pattern no. 1, 2 to pattern no. 2 etc. and then you're ready to go with any available framework that was originally trained on the MNIST database.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! It was a lot helpful. Both your suggestions are very interesting. The first one might still be ahead of my programming skills, but i'll keep an eye on it, since at a certain point  i want to learn NNs. I think i might follow the second way, because it's pretty similar to what i was thinking. The only proble, for now, is that i know how to do that in theory but not to put that in code. Thank you again!